# Part of website independent of iPhone’s zoom

Tags: iphone, web, zooming, viewport, gestures

Is it possible to have a menu bar (navigation bar) on a web site that is independent of iPhone’s zoom (i.e. with fixed width and height) while the rest of the site can be zoomed in and out?

With meta "viewport" I can set the zoom of the whole website, I want to exclude some parts.

It seems that it can't be done by using iFrames or CSS transforms.

Is it possible to be done by tracking Gestures that scale elements, and using javascript to rescale my menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPhone's zoom is a graphical thing - it does not change the html rendering of the page (although it may look at the html element for hints about what how much to zoom).
So, not really, no.